# Why the other inventory file not being process even it arrive few second from the other inventory? Using "-cmin -5" as condtion

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I have a cronjob that run every 1min to get a file from a remote server then place it in my local `$INC_INVENT` below is sample file,

```
  -rw-r--r-- 1 ansi ansi 46 Sep 21 22:34 inventory_200921223307
  -rw-r--r-- 1 ansi ansi 46 Sep 21 22:35 inventory_200921223406
```

then I have a script that will run every 5min to execute a playbook below is code. It will check first if there is a new file then execute the playbook

```
ls -1 $INC_INVENT | grep -v "process" | while read invent_file
do
   check=$( find $INC_INVENT -name $invent_file -cmin -5 )
   if [ ! -z $check ]
   then
       ansible-playbook -i $INC_INVENT/$invent_file  $MAIN/applyPatch.yml -vv >> $LOG/linuxpatching.log.$$ 2>&1
       mv  $INC_INVENT/$invent_file $PROCES
       exit
   else
      exit
   fi
done
```

Problem is only (inventory_200921223307) file is being processed, the other file (inventory_200921223406) not anymore process by the playbook. Seem not meeting the condition of " -cmin -5 " anymore? My objective is any NEW file arrive will be processed I added the -cmin -5 to avoid processing again the inventory file if it's not yet move to process dir is this bad approach or there is a better way of achieving this? Thanks in advance.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ansi ansi 46 Sep 21 22:34 inventory_200921223307
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like a design problem to me,
as in, while the first file is being processed, some time passes,
and when you try to check the next file in line, it already expires.

I would fix it by rewriting a bit the loop:

```sh
find . $INC_INVENT -cmin -5 | grep -v "process" | while read invent_file
do
       ansible-playbook -i $INC_INVENT/$invent_file  $MAIN/applyPatch.yml -vv >> $LOG/linuxpatching.log.$$ 2>&1
       mv $INC_INVENT/$invent_file $PROCES
done
```

In such way you query the relevant data first, and then simply process it without the need to check it later on in a queued loop